# ShareKit Not showing text on Facebook

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios4, sharekit

I am having some problems with ShareKit on Facebook.  I have no issues logging in on facebook, but when I try to post the text, the facebook dialog pops up, and there is no text at all in the dialog.

Here is the sharekit code in my project.

```
    // call shareKit to share the item.
    SHKItem *item =[SHKItem text: shareString];

    // Share it via facebook
    [SHKFacebook shareItem:item];
```

I checked to make sure my shareString is not blank.  No problems, the string is exactly what I expect.

Following the code all the way through ShareKit, I get to the FBConnect code in SHKFacebook.m file.

```
_fbDialog = [[FBDialog alloc] initWithURL:dialogURL params:params delegate:delegate];

then :
[_fbDialog show];
```

And even here, everything looks fine.  I have the access_token for facebook, I have the message (my share string).

```
{
"access_token" = "some long string";
actions = "Link to my app";
"app_id" = "my app id";
display = touch;
message = "Same as the share string";
"redirect_uri" = "fbconnect://success";
sdk = 2;
}
```

When I see the post screen however, it is blank.  Anyone see this before?  Is it a problem with the FBConnect or the ShareKit?

Really confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook Connect no longer allows you to pre-populate the message field.  This went into effect July 12th.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Comment: My fix is to move to the graph api.  Change SHKFacebook.m file, **send** method.

Instead of :

    [[SHKFacebook facebook] dialog:@"feed"
                       andParams:params 
                     andDelegate:self];

Use :

    [[SHKFacebook facebook] requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" 
                                       andParams:params 
                                   andHttpMethod:@"POST" 
                                     andDelegate:self];
I would rather see a form like the SHKTwitterForm that shows a preview.  Is there a fork of ShareKit that has this?